# Change a dropbox contend selecting another dropbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, drop-down-menu

I have an dropbox:

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="SORD_DREVIZ">Actul*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select style="width: 200px;max-width: 200px;" name="metadataValues['SORD_DREVIZ']" id="SORD_DREVIZ" class="required">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <c:forEach items="${comboItemsMap4['SORD_DREVIZ']}" var="comboItem">
                        <option value="${comboItem.objId}" <c:if test="${comboItem.objId eq document.metadataValues['SORD_DREVIZ']}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${comboItem.regNumber} / ${comboItem.regDate.month}-${comboItem.regDate.day}-${comboItem.regDate.year}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ACT_INEXISTENT"/> Actul nu exista in sistem
            </div>
        </div>
```

and another one:

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE">Tipul actului de reglementare*</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select style="width: 400px;max-width: 400px;" name="metadataValues['TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE']" id="TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE" class="required">
                <option value=""></option>
                <c:forEach items="${comboItemsMap['TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE']}" var="comboItem">              
                    <option value="${comboItem.value}" <c:if test="${comboItem.value eq document.metadataValues['TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE']}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${comboItem.text}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>                           
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I chenge the second dropbox, I want to change the content of the first dropbox:

```
$("#TIPUL_ACTULUI_REGLEMENTARE").change(function(){
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<c:url value="/cerere/searchByAct"/>',
            data:{act:selectedText},
            dataType: 'json',
            context:this,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //TODO - change the SORD_DREVIZ combo - I have in data what I need from server side

            },
            error:function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState=0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
                    return;
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I do that?
I have in data something like this:

```
[Object { objId=626984, regDate=1426370400000, regNumber="333"}]
```

and my combo should look like 333 / 03-15-2015

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it like this, but I don't find how to convert from Julian date to mm-dd-yyyy.

```
var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<c:url value="/cerere/searchByAct"/>',
            data:{act:selectedText},
            dataType: 'json',
            context:this,
            success:function(data){
                $('#SORD_DREVIZ').empty();
                $(data.slSordIdRegInfo).each(function()
                {
                    console.log(this.regDate);
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', this. objId).text(this.regNumber);
                    $('#SORD_DREVIZ').append(option);
                });
            },
            error:function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState=0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
                    return;
            }
        });
```